# can anyone explain this output (operating system)?

Tags: c, operating-system, pid

while i'm studying the operating system course i didnt understand why the output of the code below like this

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int value = 5;


    pid_t pid = fork();
    printf("pid = %d \n",pid);
    if (pid == 0){
        value+=15;      
        printf("Value ch :%d \n",value);
    }
    else {
        if (pid > 0) {
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Value pr :%d \n",value);
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
run
[Switching to process 24752]
Running…
pid = 24756 
pid = 0 
Value ch :20 
Value pr :5
```

if value in child became 20 why after returning from child value = to 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fork()` creates a new process, with its own address space.  This address space is filled with a copy of the contents of the original address space.  Therefore, changes made in one process don't affect the other.

In other words, it's because processes don't share memory (unless you explicitly force them to with `mmap()` and so on).

Comment: how can i print the memory adressess ?

Comment: @Bobj-C: You can print an address with `printf("%p", (void*)&value);`

Comment: i add the code inside child and parent PID's same output a hexadecimal value so ?

Comment: @Sam Hoice: The memory addresses will be the same, because they're in virtual address space.

Comment: I did not realize that, but I suppose it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Because the parent process memory is copied to the child process and further changes in the child process memory don't affect the parent's. [fork pitfalls](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html) are interesting.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to link that tutorial. It has a good bit of misinformation and bad style, the worst of which is probably the recommendation to `#ifdef __gnu_linux__` around completely standards-conformant code instead of using `#ifndef BROKEN_OS` around it and checking for broken systems at configure-time.

Comment: Agree, it just illustrates some possible effects of fork usage, maybe, in a badly manner.